# Agregar clase a un botón, según el texto que contenga

Tags: javascript, wordpress

soy novato en esto, espero entiendan si hay algún error conceptual ;)

Estoy con una tienda con Wordpress y quiero agregar una función en JavaScript en el que botón de *agregar-al-carrito* se agregue una clase según el texto que contenga (ya tengo la función que reemplaza el texto). Es para que los productos que se van agregando al carrito queden tildados de azul.
Este es el html

```
<button type="submit" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="36" class="button alt ajax_add_to_cart add_to_cart_button product_type_simple">Agregar</button>

<button type="submit" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="36" class="button alt ajax_add_to_cart add_to_cart_button product_type_simple">Ya está en el Carrito</button>
```

Estuve buscando algo de info y pude llegar a esto..

```
var elemento = document.getElementsByClassName("button alt ajax_add_to_cart add_to_cart_button product_type_simple").textContent;
if (elemento = "Está en el Carrito") {
    //Agregar Clase
    elemento.className += " blue";
} else {
    //Nada
}
```

Gracias de antemano a quien me pueda ayudar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estás haciendo en tu condicional es **reasignar** el valor de la variable a un string, por lo que la sentencia devolverá ese string haciendo que la condición sea siempre evaluada como verdadera y se cumpla. Por favor, lee los [Operadores Lógicos de JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators).

Por otro lado, si no haces nada más en la sentencia `else`, no la necesitas. Solo haces que tu código se vea más feo y desordenado.

Además, `document.getElementsByClassName` te devuelve una lista de nodos, no un nodo solamente (un nodo es un elemento), por lo que la propiedad `textContent` será `undefined`, podrías usar el [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) para poder usar los métodos nativos de un array en los elementos, ya que lo que devuelve `document.getElementsByClassName` es una lista parecida, pero no igual a un array. Una vez tengamos la lista, podrías usar [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) para saber si algún elemento de esa lista cumple la condición que pusiste

```js
const elemento = [...document.getElementsByClassName("button alt ajax_add_to_cart add_to_cart_button product_type_simple")];
if (elemento.some(e => e.textContent === "Está en el Carrito")) {
    //Agregar Clase
    elemento.filter(e => e.textContent === "Está en el Carrito").map(e => e.className += " blue");
}
```

Otra alternativa, quizás más corta a esta es usar [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) como lo hemos usado en el otro ejemplo para fltrar los elementos que cumplan la condición que buscas, pero ahora solo iremos iterando cada uno de los elementos con [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) añadiendo la clase a cada uno, porque el array que tendremos serán los elementos filtrados, es decir los únicos que cumplen la condición que hemos impuesto

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName("button alt ajax_add_to_cart add_to_cart_button product_type_simple")].filter(e => e.textContent === "Está en el Carrito").map(e => e.className += " blue");
```

Comment: @Rodrigo R. Te agradezco mucho!! Funcionaron perfecto ambas opciones.